# Segmentation vs Clustering

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, time-series, cluster-analysis, image-segmentation

I've been working on a project which I get some information from an image and then I need to separate bunch of lines in that image. so what I get in each bunch almost looks like this:

[Slide 5 in this presentation](http://es.slideshare.net/ivansanchez1988/trajectory-clustering-traclus-algorithm/5)

I am new to clustering and I've been studying different methods for clustering data in image, such as hard, soft, hierarchical,etc. and common methods such as KMeans and so on. According to my specific need for the project, for example in the above picture, I need to first cluster the whole bunch of lines and then separate the straight lines from those ones with different directions.

as far as my understanding goes, segmentation is about dividing something into pieces according to some criteria. whereas, clustering is finding regions in the image space with a different density of objects in the neigbouring regions.

Since there are not many information about the differences between these two, I would be grateful if someone explains the differences between segmentation and clustering (for instance in my case) and what kind of algorithm I have to choose according to my need.

Comment: _Segmentation_ is usually referred to images (2D space), and usually concerns "visually important" features (such as color or texture). _Clustering_ is (in general) on higher dimensional spaces. The goal of both is to create partitions with high inter class variance, and low intra class variance, according to some criteria. You can achieve segmentation through clustering, but not viceversa. You can, however, cluster the result of the segmentation.

Comment: @Miki Thanks for explaining. So for my case, since I'm just dealing with simillar type of interesting objects (trajectory lines), you think there is no need to think of Segmentation as a solution?

Comment: Exactly. You're dealing with sequences of points, or angles. If you already have such sequences, segmentation is pointless. Conversely, if you have an image with some (unknown) trajectory drawn, you'll need  to segment the image in order to extract the points that form the trajectories.

Comment: that helped a lot, thank you!